# Do schools produce/raise/educate/graduate students?

Tags: single-word-requests

My question here stems from a lack of idiomatic phrase knowledge.

Let me proceed with an example. I am looking for a suitable verb for the sentence below:

As a university taking the 21st century requirements into account,  our mission is to __________________ students who can think critically .......

I came up with this sentence for the sake of an example only, but I think I've made my point clear: What do schools do? Do they produce students? I know they educate them but I am not sure if it quite corresponds to what I am trying to say here. I want to convey the meaning of a student's graduating (from) a school with the school itself being the subject. To be more precise, does a school graduate students, too?

In Turkish, schools literally "raise" students just like parents raising children. Would it make any sense if I used it in English?

Thank you!

Comment: Schools are often said to _churn out_ students, but that’s hardly suitable in this context since it’s rather negative in tone – it sees the school as a kind of factory that just spits out students as if on a conveyor belt. _Raise_ definitely doesn’t work, but I don’t really think there’s one specific verb that’s particularly idiomatic here.

Comment: So, to be clear, you are looking for the best word that is synonymous with *our mission is to **graduate** students*? That's what you imply in the second-last paragraph. But it's not clear from the title of your question if that's the sense you're really after.

Comment: Thank you both! I think "churn out" covers my meaning here. If only it didn't have a negative vibe to it... I guess I can use "graduate" anytime but I am looking for the best option and really good alternatives because I'm translating a university's website and want to sound as natural as I can.

Answer (score 1):

This one seems popular:

> [...] our mission is to **develop** students [...]

The first [Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=school+%22our+mission+is+to+develop+students%22&oq=school+%22our+mission+is+to+develop+students%22) hits:

> Our mission is to develop students, staff, families, and parishioners in Gospel living through experiential learning.
>
> Our mission is to develop students who are equipped to be well-rounded, ethical leaders in ...
>
> Our mission is to develop students as life long learners through a balanced ...
>
> Our mission is to develop students who are active in their learning, aware of their interests, and who seek to expand and explore their knowledge through ...
>
> Our mission is to develop students who are committed disciples of Jesus Christ through an excellent, comprehensive, Biblically-integrated educational program.
>
> Our mission is to develop students as Master Learners who are able to think on their ...
>
> Our mission is to develop [students] with ...
>
> Our mission is to develop students who are independent and ...
>
> Our mission is to develop students who are active in their learning, aware of their interests, and who seek to expand and explore ...
>
> Our mission is to develop students who make an active contribution as they ...

Comment: Crikey, that sounds like awful marketing speak. I’m not surprised schools have taken to using it!

Comment: I’m against the missionary position myself.

Answer (score 1):

Whereas everyday English would say 'educate', in the example you are using 'develop' is the right word.

'Raise' is not used for students. This word ('raising children') is only really used in a parenting sense, and to a British ear, is slightly American. You would never say a school 'graduated' (or for that matter 'matriculated')

Of course in the example you gave, it could mean that you are looking to find (or recruit) them, rather than what you do once they have joined.